# VSCode Angular 2 HTML Syntax Highlighting

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

So lately I've been working on a project in Ionic that is based on Angular 2 and I fell in love with Visual Studio Code as I do enjoy its look and feel. However, I'm facing a big issue as it doesn't provide Angular 2 HTML syntax highlighting (*ngIf, *ngFor, [hidden], etc) which makes it difficult to separate regular HTML syntax from the Angular one. I've tried searching for extensions that provide this kind of highlight but was rather unsuccessful. Do any of you face the same problem and have some kind of solution?

Comment: try press F1 write `color theme` and select different color.

Comment: The problem still remains as every theme treats Angular HTML syntax the same way as regular HTML syntax. If only there was a way one could change the highlight for specific HTML attributes.

Comment: did you write html in template or templateUrl ? try update vscode to latest version.

Comment: I always write my HTML in a separate template file.

Comment: I couldn't find any VS Code extension for this currently. Looks like the [Atom language-html-angular](https://atom.io/packages/language-html-angular) extension does this and it may be possible to port the grammar to code without too much trouble

Comment: Well I ended up messing with the default HTML parser so it would recognize a new token with a specific regular expression that would recognize Angular HTML syntax. And then styled those via User Settings in the VSCode.

Comment: This one will do the trick: https://github.com/ghaschel/vscode-angular-html